# When did Sarah call Abraham "lord"?

Tags: genesis, abraham, 1-peter, sarah

Peter says that Sarah called Abraham "lord" (i.e., master) and that it was a good thing.

When did she do this? And how does Peter know this? I can't find it anywhere in scripture.

> **1 Peter 3:5,6 ESV** For this is how the holy women who hoped in God used to adorn themselves, by submitting to their own husbands, **as Sarah obeyed Abraham, calling him lord**. And you are her children, if you do good and do not fear anything that is frightening.

Comment: A good question for http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ would be, "What did the word lord mean in ancient Hebrew culture?"  Referencing these passages.

Comment: Asked here: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/what-did-sarah-mean-by-calling-abraham-her-lord

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first verse that comes to my mind is in Genesis 18:12-

> Therefore Sarah laughed within herself, saying, After I am waxed old shall I have pleasure, **my lord being old also?**

This is the only verse I can really remember in this context, and it is probably what Peter is referring to.

Answer (score -1):

There is no documentation, in the story or Abraham and Saraha, that Saraha VERBALLY called Abraham, "lord."

"Now Sarah was listening at the entrance to the tent, which was behind him. 11Abraham and Sarah were already very old, and Sarah was past the age of childbearing. 12So Sarah laughed to herself as she thought, “After I am worn out and my lord is old, will I now have this pleasure?”

Sarah called Abraham "lord" in her "thoughts."  Saraha verbally called Abraham "husband."

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks also for offering an answer. I hope you'll stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is found in the Book of Jasher (referenced in Joshua 10:13 & 2nd Sammuel 1:18)
where Sarah's prayer to God is recorded in Chapter 15:17. 1st Peter 3:6 is quoting from this verse.

Comment: There are two books called the "Book of Jasher" that you can read now, neither date earlier than the 16th century AD. They are definitely not the same book referred to in the Bible which has been lost to us.

Answer (score -3):

Peter is incorrect. When Abraham tried to ignore the situation, God spoke to Abraham and instructed him to listen to his wife. Because of this Hagar was driven off. God said man and woman would be one flesh. There are accounts in the bible where prudent women made better decisions than men did.

Comment: Referring [to this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/12775/13608) might be better support than an unsupported assertion.  (Even if your assessment is correct).